# Validated XPATH query returning blank data with IMPORTXML

Tags: xml, google-sheets

I'm trying to import a specific datapoint from World Bank data into a Google Sheet using =IMPORTXML. The specific site I am trying to query is https://api.worldbank.org/v2/country/AFG/indicator/FM.LBL.BMNY.CN?format=xml, which, as far as I can see, is a bare XML site.

The node I want to select is the first nonblank <wb:value> node using this XPath query `(//wb:value[normalize-space()])[1]`. However, when I put that query into IMPORTXML it returns the "Imported Content is Empty" error message. The full formula I'm using is:

```
=importxml("https://api.worldbank.org/v2/country/AFG/indicator/FM.LBL.BMNY.CN?format=xml", "(//wb:value[normalize-space()])[1]")
```

I built the relevant query using http://xpather.com/ and copied the content of the World Bank API call and have tested that it does select the correct node, but it doesn't want to work in Google Sheets.

I have also tested that the API call works in general with Google Sheets - using IMPORTDATA with `//*` as a query returns valid data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your situation, how about the following modified formula?

#### Modified formula:

```
=INDEX(importxml("https://api.worldbank.org/v2/country/AFG/indicator/FM.LBL.BMNY.CN?format=xml", "//*[local-name()='data']/*[local-name()='value']"),1)
```

- In this case, I used an XPath of `//*[local-name()='data']/*[local-name()='value']`. And, in order to retrieve the 1st value, I used `INDEX`.

#### Testing:

[image]

Comment: That's excellent, thanks so much - that worked. Do you know why your XPath was accepted by Google Sheets while the XPath I tried to use wasn't?

Comment: @Nick Kokay Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Now, I noticed that in this case, the XPath of `//*[local-name()='value']` can be also used instead of `//*[local-name()='data']/*[local-name()='value']`. About your XPath, in this case, when the namespace is used, I thought that `local-name()` might be suitable. So, I proposed the above XPath. If this explanation was not useful, I apologize.